# Tensorflow/Keras: Start strides at center in convolutional layer?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

If I understand convolutional layers in a neural net correctly, the stride order (for a 2-dimensional input) would be:

```
 1  2  3  4  5

 6  7  8  9 10

11 12 13 14 15
```

---

**Question:** Is there any way to change this so that it would be "spiraling outwards from the center" indstead?

Example:

```
13  5  4  3 12

14  6  1  2 11

15  7  8  9 10
```

---

**Note:** When would the starting position be relevant? Let's say the input dimension is `(5, 3)` and strides is `(4, 2)`.

Let's mark the upper left corner of the area relevant to each input. In this case the order should be

```
1 * * * 2
* * * * *
3 * * * 4
```

resulting in output dimension `(2, 2)`

as compared to

```
* * * * *
* * 1 * *
* * * * *
```

when starting in the middle, resulting in output dimension `(1, 1)`.

Comment: Convolutions by design are parallel and independent. There is no single "starting point", if the GPU is big enough. Strides just tell the placement of the kernels. All locations are then convolved simultaneously.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Yes. But let's say, the input dimension is `(3, 3)` and strides is `(4, 4)`? Is the starting point and order not relevant in this case?

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal The difference should then be in the output dimensions (I added an example).

Comment: This is an implementation idiosyncrasy due to convention. In common implementations, the column `2 ,*, 4` will be clipped before the actual convolutions even start. Check the `tensorflow` `Conv2D` source to understand the above statement.